# Flutter camera 0.8.1 make error in gradle build

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, camera

After I updated the camera plugin in my project to the latest version [camera 0.8.1](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) It causes an error when I want to compile and build on the Android platform.

I tried to change the Gradle version to fix this problem, but I couldn't fix this problem.
I provided all of my log and important files here, please help me to fix my problem, if you have any example which shows the usage of the latest camera plugin or something else, please don't hesitate to add your answer...

**1.build.gradle(app) :**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "ir.taleb.test_camera"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**2.build.gradle(project) :**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**3.pubspec.yaml :**

```
name: test_camera
description: A new Flutter application.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  camera: ^0.8.1

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

**4.flutter doctor --verbose :**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at /Users/taleb/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (6 days ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/taleb/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/taleb/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS
      development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with
        is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
      To re-install see
      https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM A107F (mobile) • R9AM905ZREJ • android-arm    • Android 10 (API 29)
    • macOS (desktop)   • macos       • darwin-x64     • macOS 11.2.3 20D91
      darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      90.0.4430.93

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

**5.Error LOG:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':camera:extractDebugAnnotations'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':camera:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find lint-gradle-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/27.1.0/lint-gradle-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/27.1.0/lint-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-checks-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/27.1.0/lint-checks-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-api-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/27.1.0/lint-api-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find intellij-core-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/27.1.0/intellij-core-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find kotlin-compiler-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/27.1.0/kotlin-compiler-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find uast-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/27.1.0/uast-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto-4.1.0-alpha01-6193524.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:4.1.0-alpha01-6193524).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/4.1.0-alpha01-6193524/aapt2-proto-4.1.0-alpha01-6193524.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: show your build.gradle(project)

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Sure, I edited my question, please look at  2.build.gradle (project) which I provided

Comment: Did you run flutter pub upgrade?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Yeah but it still not working, 

Could not find lint-gradle-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:27.1.0).

Comment: In app/build.gradle add `maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }` in buildscript{repositories{maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } } }

Comment: @UsamaAltaf it does not work...